# Lead somewhere vs lead to somewhere

Tags: verbs

On one of the pages of "Oxford Word Skills", *lead* is used without any kind of preposition:

> "A passage is a long, narrow way with walls on both sides that leads
>   somewhere..."

On the same page, it has defined *lead* as follows:

> "If something leads to a place, you can go along it to that place."

Why is *lead* sometimes used with *to* and sometimes without it? Is this actually triggered here by *somewhere*? What's the grammar behind this?

Comment: "where" (and its compounds) can be understood to contain "to". We can in fact say: *Where are you going?* or *Where are you going to?* That's why *lead somewhere/anywhere/nowhere* is correct.

Comment: "Somewhere" and "to a place" both function as adverbs.